# mouseOver and mouse Tracking in processing.js

Tags: processing, processing.js

Hello i am trying to track a mouse over a two dimensional array where in each sell i got a square what i am trying to do is when my mouse is overe some square to make it red, but when i put the mouse overe sketch a bunch of them are colored red any ideas how to fix that? Here is the code: And sorry for my english.

```javascript
int[][] back =new int[3][3];
int pad = 10, bs=100, len=pad*(back.length+1)+bs*back.length;

void setup(){
  size(500,500);
  noStroke();
}

void draw(){
 background(255); 
 rectt(0,0,width,height,color(100));
 for(int row=0;row<back.length;row++)
   for(int coll=0;coll<back[row].length;coll++){
     float x = pad+(pad+bs)*coll;
     float y = pad+(pad+bs)*row;
     rectt(x,y,bs,bs,color(150));
     if(mouseX > x && mouseY<y){
      rectt(x,y,bs,bs,color(255,0,0));
     }
   }
}


void rectt(float x, float y, float w, float h, color c){
 fill(c);
 rect(x,y,w,h);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line of code:

```javascript
if(mouseX > x && mouseY<y){
   rectt(x,y,bs,bs,color(255,0,0));
}
```

What exactly do you expect that if statement to do? Please draw out some example grids and do the if statement for a bunch of different points.

Hopefully that will demonstrate that your logic doesn't make sense here. You're checking if `mouseX > x`, which means the point is to the right of the cell. That makes sense so far. But then you're also checking if `mouseY < y`, which means the point is above the cell. That doesn't make sense! You're coloring any cells that are to the right and above the cell.

Instead, you need to check whether the mouse position is **inside** the cell. This is usually 4 checks:

- Is the mouse to the right of the left edge of the cell?
- Is the mouse to the left of the right edge of the cell?
- Is the mouse below the top edge of the cell?
- Is the mouse above the bottom edge of the cell?

You can get the right and bottom edges of the cell by adding the cell width and height to its `x` and `y` positions.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was very helpful for me i think a bit for a second and i rewrite my IF statement now it looks like that
    `if(mouseX >=x && mouseX<=x+width/x*coll+bs
        && mouseY>=y && mouseY<=y+height/y*row+bs){
        rectt(x,y,bs,bs,color(255,0,0));
      }`